# Считавшийся непотопляемым(,) корабль пересекал Атлантику

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, недопустимая-метка, определения

`Считавшийся непотопляемым(,) корабль пересекал Атлантику, столкнулся с айсбергом и затонул, унеся с собой жизни 1500 человек.`

Нужно ли обособлять определение? Можно и́ обособлять, и нéт?

Comment: Этот корабль, считавшийся непотопляемым, столкнулся с айсбергом и унес с собой жизни более 1500 человек. https://dzen.ru/a/ZKWUSC7rPiFyTvCL

Comment: @shampar Вообще, эта фраза не оттуда, а с ютьюб-канала «WTFакт». Видео называется: «Маленькие ошибки с большими последствиямм».

Comment: О цитировании принято сообщать в любых текстах. Здесь также, и не в комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Считавшийся непотопляемым,** корабль пересекал Атлантику, столкнулся с айсбергом и затонул, унеся с собой жизни 1500 человек.*

**Обособление.** Актуализация согласованного определения в препозиции, подчеркивание **предикативности** признака (можно заменить придаточным предложением:  корабль, **который** считался непотопляемым).

В общем случае оборот в препозиции **может не обособляться**, но в данном предложении оборот нужно обособить.

Определение относится к слову с неопределенным значением (***корабль***) и по смыслу может называть **сопутствующий, а не отличительный признак.**

Comment: А почему не может не обособляться?

Comment: Я же написала почему. Это стилистика данного предложения: сопутствующий, а не отличительный признак. Нельзя сказать: Титаник – это тот корабль, который считался непотопляемым. Один из таких кораблей, но не единственный.